# How do you gain reputation without asking something?

Tags: support, reputation, new-users

I'm Talha Yaser, and I need reputation to comment. How do I gain reputation without asking a question on this platform?

Comment: Start by taking the [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour) and read the [Help pages](https://superuser.com/help), especially [What is reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it?](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation)

Answer (score 2):

Welcome! This question (and related ones) come up quite often, so detailed answers have been documented on Meta Stack Exchange:

- [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214173/295232)
- [How does a lurker gain reputation to receive privilege for commenting?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/164035/how-does-a-lurker-gain-reputation-to-receive-privilege-for-commenting?noredirect=1)

> How do I gain reputation without asking a question on this platform?

A short summary:

- write answers to other people's questions (I would pick a tag of a product/OS you're familiar with and filter on unanswered questions) – each upvote will get you +10 reputation
- suggest edits to improve posts (by correcting grammar, or by clarifying unclear parts of them) – each accepted edit will get you +2 reputation

These are also mentioned in the Help Center article linked to by @Tetsujin: [What is reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it?](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation)